# python append value to list from dictionary inside dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to append 'rev' and 'tta' keys and his values into new list. How i can do that?

Here's the dict:

```
vl = {0: {'art': 5612306, 'rev': 3.0, 'report_id': 751233}, 1: {'art': 567206, 'tta': 2.8, 'report_id': 751233}}
```

What i try to do and getting error:

```
n_list = []
for elem in vl:
    n_list.append(vl[elem][1])
```

Comment: What "doesn't work"?  Do you get an error, or unexpected results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
vl = {0: {'art': 5612306, 'rev': 3.0, 'report_id': 751233}, 1: {'art': 567206, 'tta': 2.8, 'report_id': 751233}}

n_list = []
for elem in vl:
    val = vl[elem]
    if 'rev' in val:
        n_list.append(val['rev'])
    elif 'tta' in val:
        n_list.append(val['tta'])

print(n_list)
#[3.0, 2.8]
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```py
>>> vl = {0: {'art': 5612306, 'rev': 3.0, 'report_id': 751233}, 1: {'art': 567206, 'tta': 2.8, 'report_id': 751233}}
>>> [item.get('rev', item.get('tta')) for item in vl.values()]
[3.0, 2.8]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write like this, but this code only suit for this structure ,

```
    n_list = []
    for elem in vl:
        n_list.append(vl[elem][tuple(vl[elem])[1]])
```